# How to set public inline images in Knowledge Base Article

Tags: security, knowledge, images, richtextarea

### Background

I'm developing an standard FAQ using Knowledge Base Articles. I've defined an Article Type FAQ which contains a Rich Text field called "Answer".

The FAQ articles are exposed to an external web site through a custom `Apex web service`. That WS query and sort the content that should be render by the external site. 
This Apex hit the `FAQ_kav` object to get the field content.

*Note: the WS is hit by a full access API user.*

So far, everything is working fine, but:

### Issue

When the user insert an inline image using the **Rich Editor's upload function**, that image is store in something like:  `https://c.cs20.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka3m0000000XXXX&amp;feoid=00Nm0000000XXXX&amp;refid=0EMm0000000XXXX`

That domain (c.cs20.content.force.com) is checking the session and hence the image is private. Even when I've checked the article for **Public Knowledge Base channel**.

I understand that that image will be stored as a document, but I'm not abled to check as "*Externally Available Image"* for standard docs.

### Question

Is any security setting that I should enabled in order to **expose public access to that content**(images).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expose the image through a site. You only need to change the instance url by the site home page.

Also, you need to establish the article as public.

Site Profile Changes:

- Set field where image is placed as visible.
- Set Read permission to object where image is placed.
- Go to "Category Group Visibility Settings" section and set visibility to "All Categories" in the article/s group/s.

For example:

If you have this site:

> https://mysite-developer-edition.cs20.force.com/home

And your original image url is:

> https://c.cs20.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka3m0000000XXXX&feoid=00Nm0000000XXXX&refid=0EMm0000000XXXX

Your public image would be:

> https://mysite-developer-edition.cs20.force.com/home/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka3m0000000XXXX&feoid=00Nm0000000XXXX&refid=0EMm0000000XXXX

This workarround would work with any image in a Rich Text Area.

Comment: Hi @robertinhosedinho what if my Salesforce instance does not have a custom site per se but I am trying to expose RTA fields on the case objects?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way of working with the storage used for rich text fields, I've hit a similar scenario in the past and couldn't find a way around it.

You can specify a URL for images, so an alternative (if security is not required on the images) would be to host the images off-platform (maybe using Dropbox or similar for ease-of-use) of to put them into public documents. That said, getting the public URL of documents is a bit fiddly in itself!

Comment: Yes, I thought in that option but I'm a bit intriguing about how Public Knowledge Base 2 App from appexchange (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU) can accomplish that.